# How to logged out the user if they logged out from one browser on same computer in servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I have one application in which i am restricting the user for multiple loggin from different devices. For that i took two column in my table status and ip. If user already logged in from one computer then he is able to login again from same machine but when he try to logged in from another then the ip of new machine will be assigned. but he is able to access from previous computer. Why? how to logged out him? And also if i logged out from one browser he is able to access from another browser if he logged in from both browser. How to logged out him from all browsers?
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    doPost(request, response);
}

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    System.out.println("LoginServlet..........");
    InetAddress address;
    //String hostname;
    byte[] ip = new byte[0];
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);

    LoginDTO loginDTO = (LoginDTO) session.getAttribute("loginDTO");

    int noOfCartItems = 0;
    session.setAttribute("noOfCartItems", noOfCartItems);

    Connection con = null;
    try {
        String operation = request.getParameter("operation");
        if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase("signin")) {
            String mobile_email = request.getParameter("mobile_email");
            String password = request.getParameter("password");
            address = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
         ip = address.getAddress();
         String ipAddress = com.oeuvretc.util.RawIPToString.getIpAddress(ip);
         System.out.println(ipAddress);
            con = ConnectionManager.getConnection();

            PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM view_user_details  WHERE (mobile=? OR email_id=?) AND user_password=?");
            ps.setString(1, mobile_email);
            ps.setString(2, mobile_email);
            ps.setString(3, password);
            ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();

            if(rs.next())
            {
                HttpSession s=request.getSession();
                s.setAttribute("mob", mobile_email);
                out.print(1);
                String ipadd=rs.getString("ip");
                String stat=rs.getString("status");
                if(ipadd.equals("")||ipadd.equals(ipAddress))   
                {
                    PreparedStatement ps3=con.prepareStatement("update user_registration set status=?, ip=? where (mobile=? or email_id=?)");
                    ps3.setString(1,"ONLINE");
                    ps3.setString(2, ipAddress);
                    ps3.setString(3,mobile_email);
                    ps3.setString(4,mobile_email);
                    int count=ps3.executeUpdate();
                     if (loginDTO == null) {
                         loginDTO = new LoginDTO();
                         loginDTO.setLoginID(mobile_email);
                         loginDTO.setPassword(password);

                         session.setAttribute("loginDTO", loginDTO);
                         session.setAttribute("loginStatus", "logged-in");
                     }

                         PersonalInfoDTO personalInfoDTO = new PersonalInfoDTO();
                         if (rs.getString("fname") != null) {
                             personalInfoDTO.setFirstName(rs.getString("fname"));
                         }
                         if (rs.getString("lname") != null) {
                             personalInfoDTO.setLastName(rs.getString("lname"));
                         }

                         String name = null;
                         if (rs.getString("fname") != null) {
                             name = rs.getString("fname");
                         }
                         if (rs.getString("lname") != null) {
                             name = name + " " + rs.getString("lname");
                         }
                         if (name != null) {
                             personalInfoDTO.setName(name);
                         }

                         if (rs.getString("email_id") != null) {
                             personalInfoDTO.setEmail(rs.getString("email_id"));
                         }
                         if (rs.getString("mobile") != null) {
                             personalInfoDTO.setMobile(rs.getString("mobile"));
                         }
                         if (rs.getString("gender") != null) {
                             personalInfoDTO.setGender(rs.getString("gender"));
                         }
                         if (rs.getString("blood_group") != null) {
                             personalInfoDTO.setBloodGroup(rs.getString("blood_group"));
                         }
                         if (rs.getString("dob") != null) {
                             personalInfoDTO.setDOB(rs.getString("dob"));
                         }
                         if (rs.getString("height_feet") != null) {
                             personalInfoDTO.setHeightFeet(rs.getString("height_feet"));
                         }
                         if (rs.getString("height_inch") != null) {
                             personalInfoDTO.setHeightInch(rs.getString("height_inch"));
                         }
                         if (rs.getString("height_cm") != null) {
                             personalInfoDTO.setHeightCentiMeter(rs.getString("height_cm"));
                         }
                         if (rs.getString("weight_hg") != null) {
                             personalInfoDTO.setWeightKG(rs.getString("weight_hg"));
                         }
                         if (rs.getString("weight_lbs") != null) {
                             personalInfoDTO.setWeightLBS(rs.getString("weight_lbs"));
                         }

                         loginDTO.setPersonalInfoDTO(personalInfoDTO);

                         AddressDTO addressDTO = new AddressDTO();
                         if (rs.getString("locality") != null) {
                             addressDTO.setLocality(rs.getString("locality"));
                         }
                         if (rs.getString("pincode") != null) {
                             addressDTO.setPincode(rs.getString("pincode"));
                         }
                         if (rs.getString("addr") != null) {
                             addressDTO.setAddr(rs.getString("addr"));
                         }
                         if (rs.getString("landmark") != null) {
                             addressDTO.setLandmark(rs.getString("landmark"));
                         }
                         if (rs.getString("Cityname") != null) {
                             addressDTO.setCity(rs.getString("Cityname"));
                         }
                         if (rs.getString("Statename") != null) {
                             addressDTO.setState(rs.getString("Statename"));
                         }
                         if (rs.getString("Countryname") != null) {
                             addressDTO.setCountry(rs.getString("Countryname"));
                         }

                         loginDTO.setAddressDTO(addressDTO);

                         //loginDTO.setImage(rs.getBinaryStream("image"));
                         loginDTO.setProfilePic(rs.getString("image"));

                         //System.out.println(rs.getString("image"));

                         // fetch if any item is available in the user cart or not
                         PreparedStatement ps1 = con.prepareStatement("SELECT test_kit FROM user_registration WHERE mobile=? OR email_id=?");
                         ps1.setString(1, loginDTO.getLoginID());
                         ps1.setString(2, loginDTO.getLoginID());
                         ResultSet rs1 = ps1.executeQuery();
                         if (rs1.next()) {
                             InputStream is = rs1.getBinaryStream(1);
                             if (is != null) {
                                 ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(is);
                                 HashMap<String, CartDTO> mapOfCartDTO = (HashMap<String, CartDTO>) ois.readObject();
                                 session.setAttribute("mapOfCartDTO", mapOfCartDTO);

                                 noOfCartItems = mapOfCartDTO.size();
                                 session.setAttribute("noOfCartItems", noOfCartItems);
                             }
                         }




                 } 
                else{

                 out.print(2);
                    PreparedStatement ps3=con.prepareStatement("update user_registration set status=?, ip=? where (mobile=? or email_id=?)");
                    ps3.setString(1,"OFFLINE");
                    ps3.setString(2, "");
                    ps3.setString(3,mobile_email);
                    ps3.setString(4,mobile_email);
                    int count=ps3.executeUpdate();

                    System.out.println("Already Logged In. from another device.");
                }

             }
            else{
            out.print(0);
                System.out.println("Invalid Username or Password");

            }


        } 
    }}
```

public class LogoutServlet extends HttpServlet {

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    doPost(request, response);
}

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
     System.out.println("LogoutServlet..........");
     Connection con = null;

     HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
     HttpSession s=request.getSession();
     String mob=(String) s.getAttribute("mob");
     String siginThrough = (String) session.getAttribute("siginThrough");
     try{
         con = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
         PreparedStatement ps3=con.prepareStatement("update user_registration set status=?, ip=? where (mobile=? or email_id=?)");
         ps3.setString(1,"OFFLINE");
        ps3.setString(2, "");
        ps3.setString(3,mob);
        ps3.setString(4,mob);
        int count=ps3.executeUpdate();
         session.invalidate();

     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }


     //response.sendRedirect(getServletContext().getInitParameter("baseURL_USER"));
     //response.sendRedirect("/scylla/");
     if (siginThrough != null) {
         if (siginThrough.equals("facebook")) {
             response.getWriter().print(siginThrough);
         } else if (siginThrough.equals("google")) {
             response.getWriter().print(siginThrough);
         }
     } else {
         response.getWriter().print(1);
     }

 }
```

}

Comment: please share code done so far.

Comment: what are you asking, `from other devices on same computer.`..?

Comment: The java tools for that are a SessionListener to keep a track of active sessions with user name and IP and a filter to close unwanted sessions. But without code I cannot say more

Comment: Will you please explain me with code sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a parameter to achieve this.

One to contain the sessionvalidation, which should be a combination of IP and a boolean.  eg (127.0.0.1-true)

you set the boolean as true when he logins from a browser and set as false once he logs out. Add a check in all pages to check this parameter to be true, and also on the IP of the accessing system and the IP in this variable. so that when he logs out, he will not be able to access from other browsers / computers.

Comment: I took one status column for that. if he login the status will be online and offline when he logout

Comment: But suppose i login from chrome, and then login from firefox. when i logout from firefox, the column of table got updated i.e oflline and ip is clear. but on chrome i am still able to access my profile. How to logout from all browser if i logout from one browser.

Comment: You should validate the session based on the parameter on every page. So when you logout from firefox and try from chrome, you will check this param on load, which will contain false and must invalidate the session.